# Update method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to update a table(MySQL DB) from the JSON received for a different table controller. I have an "Lists" Controller(for List table in DB) and a "Table" (for Tables table in DB)Controller. I get the JSON to insert a new row in Lists table. Now from the JSON received, I need to pick the table number and update the Tables table too. Below is the JSON recieved

```
Started POST "/lists.json" for 192.168.1.2 at 2013-08-26 16:55:51 +0530
  Processing by ListsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"list"=>[{"amount"=>"10.50", "orderno"=>"0220130826163623", "quan
tity"=>"1", "itemname"=>"Patatas Ali Oli", "tableno"=>"02", "ordstatus"=>"ordere
d"}, {"amount"=>"10.50", "orderno"=>"0220130826163623", "quantity"=>"1", "itemna
me"=>"Garlic Bread", "tableno"=>"02", "ordstatus"=>"ordered"}, {"amount"=>"12.50
", "orderno"=>"0220130826163623", "quantity"=>"1", "itemname"=>"Entrecote A La P
lancha", "tableno"=>"02", "ordstatus"=>"ordered"}, {"amount"=>"10.50", "orderno"
=>"0220130826163623", "quantity"=>"1", "itemname"=>"Pollo Al Horno", "tableno"=>
"02", "ordstatus"=>"ordered"}]}
```

From the above JSON i need to pick the `"tableno"=>"02"` and update my Tables row for tableno=02. Below is the code I have written in Lists Controller :

```
def create
    lists = params[:list].collect{|list_attributes| List.new(list_attributes)}
    table = Table.find(:tablabel => List.tableno,:tabstatus => 'reserved');

    valid,not_valid = lists.partition{|list| list.valid?}

    if not_valid.blank?
      lists.map(&:save)
      @lists = lists
      format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @list, status: :created, location: @list }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

Problem is the Lists table is getting updated successfully but extracting and updating Tables part is not working. 
I am just a beginner in Rails so not sure what I am missing. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look you collect the objects in lists variables now in spite of this `List.tableno` use `lists.first.tableno`  or `lists[i].tableno` here i can be 1,2....any number

so

Rails >= 3.2

For find

`table=Table.where("tablabel = ? AND tabstatus = ?",lists.first.tableno, 'reserved' )`

For Update

`table.first.update_attributes(tablabel: lists.first.tableno, tabstatus: 'reserved' )`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but now getting ArgumentError (Unknown key: tablabel) error. tablabel & tabstatus are the column names for my table.

Comment: your table model name is `Table`?

Comment: can you please show me `Table.attributes` or `Table.column_names` after trying in rails console

Comment: irb(main):008:0> Table.column_names
=> ["tabcode", "tablabel", "tabstatus"]

Comment: @Mischa which one is not valid?

Comment: @Gaurav did you add attr_accessible in  Table model ? although it is not related hope you are using rails >= 3

Comment: I didn't add this. I created models and controllers using scaffold. SO wasn't sure if need to add explicitly. Let me trying adding it.

Comment: @Mischa did you use squeel ? it is valid for squeel

Comment: Tried by adding attr_accessible but still no luck. Same error.

Comment: Tried as suggested. No error this time but its updating only lists table, still no update in other table. Do I need to give values for all 3 columns for table update.

Comment: so you want to update Table table? `find/where` is not an `update` method

Comment: for update Table you have to do `table.update_attributes(tablabel: lists.first.tableno, tabstatus: 'reserved')` and remember `table` is the instance of Table what you get by `find/where`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36256/discussion-between-gaurav-and-rajarshi-das)

Comment: sorry @Gaurav it is not opening please see my post I have separated

Comment: Yes. i tried as suggested but now getting NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for []:ActiveRecord: error. Seems like I need to define update_attribute menthod in Active record. Just figuring out how to do that.

Comment: @Gaurav yes it is not `update_attributes` problem look into your error it is got [] empty array when you find table instance and you want to update it....

Comment: do you have any data in tables table?

Comment: yes I do have. Got it. My table has tablabel value as Table02 and not 02. Thats why its not fetching any result. Seems like I need to concatenate Table before this statement. Will try and let you know.

Comment: ok....please look into my post I have updated also if your table Table has any value it will be updated...thanks

Comment: I didn't do negative vote. Infact many thanks to you for helping me out. I am still stuck. Same No Method error method error: NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation
:0x39a9620>):

Comment: Ahh!! Finally it worked but with first its updating first record in my table. Actually Table02 is the second entry. So its updating but the incorrect record.

Comment: Table02 is the record for which i need to update status as 'reserved'. Find command I believe is fetching correct record. But Table.first is updating the status of first record/row in my table as 'reserved'.

Comment: yes use where to find the result if you use rails >=3...by the way thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajarshi. Finally its working as expected. Thanks again for everything.

Comment: @Gaurav, how did you fix it? I think you should be using `update_all`. See my answer.

Comment: @Mischa I was doing incorrectly by using Table.first so it was updating first record in Table. Instead it should have been table.first. Now trying with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class):

```
Table.where(:tablabel => lists.first.tableno).update_all(:tabstatus => 'reserved')
```

This will look for the record where `tablabel == lists.first.tableno` and then update the `tabstatus` to `"reserved"`. As a bonus it will do it one query.

Comment: Thanks Mischa. The above works with little change (:tablable => lists.first.tableno).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I copied that part from your question. The point was using `update_all`.

Answer (score -1):

`List.tableno` do not gives `'02'` ; Try to use `lists.first.tableno` instead (I assume from your question that all `List` of the request have the same table, so I just pick the first one)  :

```
table = Table.find_by_tablabel_and_tabstatus(lists.first.tableno, 'reserved')
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried as suggested but its now giving ArgumentError (Unknown key: tablabel) error. tablabel & tabstatus are the column names for my table.

Comment: @Gaurav As Mischa pointed out, the `find` was not valid. I've updated my answer to use a dynamic finder. See guide 3.2: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders